# How to remove elements of array in order of index range?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I have an array:

```
const savings = ["+10$", "-22.50$", "+5$", "+22.40$", "-3.5$"];
```

I want to show elements only in a certain range of array indexes. For example: how to show everything between array index 1 (-22.50$) and array index 3 (+22.50$)? All elements with lower or higher indexes should be removed.

Comment: ... i.e, : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do so:

### slice (returns new array)

`savings.slice(1,4) // ['-22.50$', '+5$', '+22.40$']`

### splice (modifies array)

`savings.splice(1,3)  // ['-22.50$', '+5$', '+22.40$']`

---

...plus many other more complicated techniques including but not limited to:

### filter (returns new array)

in this case it's effectively just a `.slice`.

```
// ['-22.50$', '+5$', '+22.40$']
savings.filter((price, index) => index >= 1 && index <= 4)
```